# Get list of items based on user id (from array of user id) firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch the list of **devices** based on **user id** from the array of users list. data base shown below.

```
{
  "devices" : {
    "aglow6534" : {                                // Device ID
      "icon" : "switch",
      "name" : "AC",
      "state" : {
        "switch" : true
      },
      "type" : "RLY",
      "users" : {
        "rIXU5HucbVMTt3foI3AG7q5wBND3" : true      // User ID
      }
    },
    "aglow8728" : {                                // Device ID
      "icon" : "bulb",
      "name" : "bulb",
      "state" : {
        "intensity" : 45,
        "switch" : true
      },
      "type" : "DIMR",
      "users" : {
        "YBJAlwc0vQSmd1TYe190Of8V57y1" : true,     // User ID
        "rIXU5HucbVMTt3foI3AG7q5wBND3" : true      // User ID
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "YBJAlwc0vQSmd1TYe190Of8V57y1" : {             // User ID
      "age" : 28,
      "name" : "vipul garg"
    },
    "rIXU5HucbVMTt3foI3AG7q5wBND3" : {             // User ID
      "age" : 17,
      "name" : "puneet"
    }
  }
}
```

These are my rules, i tried my best to fetch data, please help i almost spend 2 days on it.

```
{
  "rules": {
      "devices" : {
            ".read" : "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('devices').hasChild(data.child('/').val())",

      }
   },
}
```

Required Result:

Example 1: let User Id: **YBJAlwc0vQSmd1TYe190Of8V57y1**

```
"devices" : {
    "aglow8728" : {
      "icon" : "bulb",
      "name" : "bulb",
      "state" : {
        "intensity" : 45,
        "switch" : true
      },
      "type" : "DIMR",
      "users" : {
        "YBJAlwc0vQSmd1TYe190Of8V57y1" : true,
        "rIXU5HucbVMTt3foI3AG7q5wBND3" : true
      }
    }
  },
```

Example 2: let User Id: **rIXU5HucbVMTt3foI3AG7q5wBND3**

```
"devices" : {
    "aglow6534" : {
      "icon" : "switch",
      "name" : "AC",
      "state" : {
        "switch" : true
      },
      "type" : "RLY",
      "users" : {
        "rIXU5HucbVMTt3foI3AG7q5wBND3" : true
      }
    },
    "aglow8728" : {
      "icon" : "bulb",
      "name" : "bulb",
      "state" : {
        "intensity" : 45,
        "switch" : true
      },
      "type" : "DIMR",
      "users" : {
        "YBJAlwc0vQSmd1TYe190Of8V57y1" : true,
        "rIXU5HucbVMTt3foI3AG7q5wBND3" : true
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fully understand [Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)  first  and other 8 links in `Security & Rules` section

Your rules is wrong on syntax. It should be something like this, maybe

```
{
  "rules": {
    "devices": {
      "$devices_id": {
        ".read": "true", 
        ".write": "false" // false if want to read only
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$users_id": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $users_id" // this is for If you wanted to restrict access to this data such that only the logged-in user can see their own data
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $users_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prior response, but still i can't get the device list based on user id. here is my query.

FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('devices').orderByChild('users').equalTo(user.uid);

Comment: I am not sure, but i think `equalTo()` will compare it with the `value` not the `key` so with your structure `"YBJAlwc0vQSmd1TYe190Of8V57y1" (key) : true (value)` it won't match